# iReport 4.1.3: Unable to add jars and folders to classpath in Win7

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I'm running the iReport 4.1.3 using Java 5 in Windows 7. It used to run perfectly with XP. Now  as i'm trying to add jars or folders it is throwing ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in the logs. Are there any compatibility issues with Win7.

Can I modify the classpath file in the software without using GUI. Any pointers will be helpful. Thanks.

Here is the log:

```
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3184
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2.getFileChooserIcon(Win32ShellFolder2.java:748)
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolderManager2.get(Win32ShellFolderManager2.java:248)
    at sun.awt.shell.ShellFolder.get(ShellFolder.java:221)
    at com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel$LazyWindowsIcon.createValue(WindowsLookAndFeel.java:1873)
    at javax.swing.UIDefaults.getFromHashtable(UIDefaults.java:185)
    at javax.swing.UIDefaults.get(UIDefaults.java:130)
    at javax.swing.MultiUIDefaults.get(MultiUIDefaults.java:44)
    at javax.swing.UIDefaults.getIcon(UIDefaults.java:411)
    at javax.swing.UIManager.getIcon(UIManager.java:613)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicFileChooserUI.installIcons(BasicFileChooserUI.java:237)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicFileChooserUI.installDefaults(BasicFileChooserUI.java:219)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicFileChooserUI.installUI(BasicFileChooserUI.java:135)
    at com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsFileChooserUI.installUI(WindowsFileChooserUI.java:126)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.setUI(JComponent.java:653)
    at javax.swing.JFileChooser.updateUI(JFileChooser.java:1755)
    at javax.swing.JFileChooser.setup(JFileChooser.java:366)
    at javax.swing.JFileChooser.<init>(JFileChooser.java:341)
    at javax.swing.JFileChooser.<init>(JFileChooser.java:300)
    at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.options.IReportPanel.jButtonAddClasspathItemActionPerformed(IReportPanel.java:2216)
    at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.options.IReportPanel.access$2000(IReportPanel.java:84)
    at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.options.IReportPanel$27.actionPerformed(IReportPanel.java:938)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1849)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2169)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:420)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:258)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:5501)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3135)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5266)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:1966)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:3968)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2024)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:3803)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4212)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:3892)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:3822)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2010)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:1778)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:3803)
[catch] at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:463)
    at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:104)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:157)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:149)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:110)
```

Comment: `Now as i'm trying to add jars or folders it is throwing ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in the logs` - what do you mean? Did you add jars manually?

Comment: Not manually, it was through GUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is a issue with the jdk5. Updating to jdk7 worked. Here is the link

http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/531699/unable-add-folder-options-classpath